# Using Dagger in AWS lambda with refreshing module periodically

Tags: java, aws-lambda, dagger

I have a serverless application deployed using AWS Lambda. I'm using java8 as my language as I am also using Dagger for DI. One of the dependencies I'm calling has multiple endpoints I can use (It has the concept of multiple endpoints to ensure availability).

Now, this application needs to call the downstream service with the endpoint which is geographically close. I have a method which returns me the closest endpoint based on geographic distance. I'm trying to understand how I can get the Dagger module to "refresh" periodically so that its able to redirect it to the correct endpoint?  I have some relevant code below to illustrate the use case.

```
@Provider
@Singleton
public MyDownstreamClient downstreamClient() {
    String endpointUrl = getClosestEndpoint(); 
    return MyDownstreamClient.builder()
        .endpoint(endpointURL) <-- This will change often based on the closest endpoint
        .arguments(someArguments)
        .build();
}
```

Now, I'm trying to understand as to how this endpointURL can dynamically be generated. My confusion here is with the fact that since the Dagger provider isn't invoked on every API call/request, it would choose the same endpoint. I looked into the idea of instantiating the client inside my actual business logic and that seemed too expensive.

I'm trying to understand if there's a way by which we can force the Dagger module to refreshed periodically of some sort? Is that a possibility?